# How to get HWNDs of all windows present on a given monitor?

Tags: c++, winapi

`GetDesktopWindow()` returns only the primary desktop. I've also tried `EnumDisplayMonitors()`, but that doesn't return the desktop handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the functions that are available, as follows:

Method 1 (less accurate for windows overlapping a monitor boundary)

1. Enumerate all windows (`EnumWindows()`)
2. Use `MonitorFromWindow()` to ignore the ones that <strike>aren't on the monitor</strike> are on a monitor other than the one you care about.

Method 2 (more accurate)

1. Get the bounds of the monitor you care about (`GetMonitorInfo()` function)
2. Enumerate all windows (`EnumWindows()`)
3. Check each window's outline rectangle (`GetWindowRect()` for XP, otherwise `DwmGetWindowAttribute(DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS)`) to see if it intersects (`IntersectRect()`) with the monitor rectangle.

Comment: Method 2 may be not that simple. A maximized window occupies more space than the monitor size, so the `IntersectRect` method could return false positives. E. g. on my single-monitor system (1920x1200), a maximized Notepad window has these coordinates as reported by Spy++: (-9, -9)-(1929, 1162), 1938x1171

Comment: @zett42: Correct that you aren't just checking for a non-zero intersection, you want to look for a certain minimum width and height of the intersection rectangle.  But at least you have control over the decision, unlike calls to `MonitorFromWindow()`.

Comment: I just did a quick test, `DwmGetWindowAttribute()` with `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` returns the correct (visible) coordinates of a maximized window. Even for non-maximized windows it will be more accurate than `GetWindowRect` as it excludes the area occupied by the window shadow.

Comment: @zett42: Thanks for that suggestion, added that it's a better way of getting window rectangle for Vista onwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EnumWindows` function and then check that window belongs to the specific monitor:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(_In_ HWND hwnd, _In_ LPARAM lParam) noexcept
{
    auto const h_monitor{::MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL)};
    if(h_monitor == g_h_target_minitor)
    {
        // Do something...
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `MonitorFromWindow` returns the same handle value as `EnumDisplayMonitors`?

Comment: @zett42 yes, display is guaranteed to keep the same handle value while it is a part of the desktop.

Comment: I think this [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/hmonitor-and-the-device-context) answers it: _"A physical display has the same HMONITOR as long as it is part of the desktop. When a WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message is sent, any monitor may be removed from the desktop and thus its HMONITOR becomes invalid or has its settings changed._" -- So unless a monitor is disconnected while `EnumWindows()` runs, it should be safe to compare `HMONITOR` handles.

Comment: The problem with this method is in its handling of windows that exist on multiple monitors.  (It isn't correct to say a window "belongs" to a monitor, for essentially the same reason)

Comment: @BenVoigt Windows does have the concept of what you could call "most significant monitor", which is the monitor that "most" of a window is on. It's used in the real world in a mixed-DPI system when Windows needs to scale a window. Depends what the OP wants to do with the data I guess.